# MySQL aggregate function problem

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

In the following example, why does the `min()` query return results, but the `max()` query does not?

```
mysql> create table t(id int, a int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

mysql> insert into t(id, a) values(1, 1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> insert into t(id, a) values(1, 2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from t
    -> ;
+------+------+
| id   | a    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t where a < 4;
+------+------+
| id   | a    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t where a < 4 having a = max(a);
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t where a < 4 having a = min(a);
+------+------+
| id   | a    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The query is of course invalid in all other RDBMSs. What do you expect it to return?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `HAVING` clause is used to filter groups of rows. You reference `min(a)` and `max(a)` which (in the absence of any `GROUP BY` clause) aggregate over all `a` values in the table but then use a comparison against a single `a` value.

So which `a` value is MySQL supposed to use? All other RDBMSs that I know of would throw an error at this point however MySQL does allow this. [From the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)

> Standard SQL does not permit the `HAVING` clause to name any column
>   not found in the `GROUP BY` clause unless it is enclosed in an aggregate
>   function. MySQL permits the use of such columns to simplify
>   calculations. This extension assumes that the nongrouped columns will
>   have the same group-wise values. **Otherwise, the result is
>   indeterminate.**

So in your case from the results you are getting it appears that it ended up using `1` as the scalar value for `a` but this behaviour is not guaranteed and it could equally well have used `2` or any other existing `a` value.

Comment: And to prove the indeterminacy of the results, you can add a row which has `a=0`. Now both your statements will return no rows.

Comment: The correct way to do this is to use a subquery: `select * from t where a = (select min(a) from t);`