# MAX on two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

I wonder if there is better way to get max from column c1 and then max from column c2 for selected rows than

```
SELECT MAX(c1) , MAX(c2) FROM t GROUP BY c1 HAVING c1 = MAX(c1)
```

Comment: [The results of your current query are not guaranteed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7297674/73226)

Comment: @MartinSmith Are you sure ? c1 is in GROUP BY

Comment: @xdazz No, it yields all pairs then, and I want only MAX c2 for each (or max) c1

Comment: SO Why are you select max(c1) but you group by c1 ??? Show the data example.

Comment: @ts. - Yes. You can't mix an aggregated `C1` and a non aggregated `C1` and expect deterministic results. That would be invalid in all other RDBMSs except MySQL. See the example in the linked question where it "works" for `MIN` but not `MAX`

Comment: What indexes do you have on your table?

Comment: @Martijn c1 and c2 are both indexed separately

Comment: Your best bet for performance tuning might be to make an index combining both. Whether it helps depends on the definition of the rest of the table and the distribution of data, but MySQL might be able to execute the SQL referring only the single index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT Max(t2.c1) as C1, 
       Max(t1.c2) as C2 
FROM   t t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(c1) AS C1 
                   FROM   t) t2 
               ON t1.c1 = t2.c1
```

Comment: this is exactly what OP asked for, even if i have my doubts if it is what they need..

Comment: Should be `MAX(t1.c2) AS C2` actually.

Answer (score 1):

Just read your comment on hkutluay's response, this might be what you want:

```
select MAX(colName)
from
(select col1 as colName
from tableName
union
select col2
from tableName) subqueryName
```

Comment: @casperOne - I'm not sure what you did that edit for, but it's completely changed my answer. Maybe you meant to edit my OTHER answer? I see you deleted that one. But this edit is not my proposed solution at all!

Comment: SeanW: There's very little reason to have *two* answers.  I'm happy to revert this back, but we don't take a shotgun approach to things here, if you have an answer, then post *one* answer.  It's perfectly OK to show two different approaches in a single answer.

Comment: Ok cool. Won't be adding >1 answer anytime soon! Just seems odd that you kept the zero-voted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure whether you want all distinct c1's or just the maximum.

If you want all c1's:

```
SELECT c1, MAX(c2) FROM t GROUP BY c1;
```

If you want only the maximum c1:

```
SELECT c1, c2 FROM t ORDER BY c1 DESC, c2 DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know mysql does not have CTE's; but because the question is also marked SQL, and the CTE is a reasonable clean solution for the subquery, for completeness here is a CTE-version:

```
WITH zmax AS (
        SELECT MAX(v1) AS v1
        FROM ztable
        )
SELECT zt.v1
        , MAX(zt.v2) AS v2
FROM ztable zt
JOIN zmax mx ON zt.v1 = mx.v1
GROUP BY zt.v1
        ;
```

Comment: MySQL does have derived tables though.

Comment: That's what I said. I added it for completeness (and future reference). And even if your favorite tool is a hammer, it is still useful to know about the existence of screwdrivers, IMHO.

Comment: Is your answer then essentially showing how to use a screwdriver to do a job you are going to use a hammer for anyway? :)

Comment: Regarding the `sql` tag in a MySQL question, I think its point is to indicate that the question is about a *query for MySQL* as opposed to questions about managing/administrating a MySQL server/database (which does not necessarily imply the necessity of writing queries).

Comment: Anyway, you could just rewrite the CTE in the form of a "normal" subselect to make your answer more valid for this question.

Comment: Yes, it could also be *homework* (although there is no homework tag it still looks like homework to me) , and the school has chosen mysql as *the SQL implementation* @AndriyM: no, that solution was already present in the other answers. A bit of diversity does not harm, IMO